# Getting RTSP video resolution via LibVLC/MediaPlayer/Media on android

Tags: android, video, vlc, rtsp, libvlc

I'm having trouble to get my RTSP stream resolution from libraries provided by libvlc.

I know that the information is somewhere in the code, and it was printed on console, but I'm not where to access them, to get proper "int"from a method provided by vlc. Hopefully someone can help me out with this :)

[Screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik5mO.png)

Comment: please don't use screenshots for code or logs. Share the text  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: which wrapper are you using?